# Rack breaks bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rack

I have a personal site I'm trying to deploy using rack to heroku. When I open the index.html file on my machine, everything looks and works fine. But when I use rackup to run it locally, all my Bootstrap styling is gone. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Can you post the <script> and <style> tags that you're using to include bootstrap?  Maybe the paths are resolving differently on your server vs. your local machine.

Comment: Here you go:
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: try adding a slash in the beginning, e.g. changing `dist` to `/dist`